# How to find the maximum value in a list without using Built-in Functions in python?

Tags: python, max, lis

I'd like to create a function that will print the max value within a list of numbers.

Comment: Are you familiar with the built-in `max` function?

Comment: I think you should do your homeworks on your own, if you ever want to learn something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont know python but the pseudocode would look something like this

```
max = –2147483648

for each integer n in collection
   if n > max
      max = n
```

It loops through every number in a collection. If the number (n) is bigger than the previous maximum, the maximum is set to be equal to n.

Comment: doesn't work if all values < 0

Comment: @m.wasowski It does now ;)

Comment: @m.wasowski I'm sorry if I'm not the best programmer in the world. But I'm pretty sure the OP got what he was asking for.

Comment: he should do this on his own. And general algorithm is: 1) if collection is empty, return None or raise error. 2) max := first element 3) ... then your code X)... return max

Comment: @m.wasowski Very well, then. Glad you wanted to help him some more =)

Comment: Integers in Python [can be of arbitrary size](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) - any solution which assumes they're limited to 32 bits will fail for some valid inputs.

Comment: ... and in any case, the question specifies "numbers" rather than "integers". What happens with the list `[-1.0e10, -1.0e12, -1.0e11]`?